# How to mute and unmute it on the onPause and onResume

Tags: android, audio, onresume, onpause, mute

I'm having a problem when I set the audio to Mute on the `onPause()` and in the `onResume()` I try to unmute it but without success.

Code:

```
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
            setStreamMute(true);        
         }

    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
            setStreamMute(false);
        }

    public void setStreamMute (boolean state){
            Log.d(TAG,"SetMute: "+state);
            myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            myAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, state);
      }
```

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Try to use `applicationContext` e.g. `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)`

Comment: May be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908962/setstreammute-never-unmutes

Comment: Same Problem @iTech didn't unmute it.

Comment: @A--C thanks But I Still with the same problem ><

Comment: The mute requests are cumulative, so you must have an equal amount of unmute requests to fully unmute the stream. Is there anywhere else in your applicatin you are sending a mute request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer ourSong;
int length; // To save the last seconds where the music has paused
```

In your **OnCreate**

```
ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(yourActivity.this, YourSong);
        ourSong.setLooping(true);
ourSong.start();
```

In you **pause** function

```
ourSong.pause();
length = ourSong.getCurrentPosition();
```

In you **resume** function

```
ourSong.seekTo(length);
ourSong.start();
```

#### Note:

you should make a folder `row` and then `YourSong` has to be like this `R.raw.yoursong`

Comment: If the `onShop()` is called it is better to save the length in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: depends of your application, but almost true