# android mute the background music using sharedpreferences

Tags: android

i has to develop an android application . It allow the user to mute or unmute the background music. If the user had presses on the mute button, when the activity is intent to next activity, it background music also should be in mute mode. i had refer to this  [mute just the background music of my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947890/mute-just-the-background-music-of-my-app) , but still face some problem.
This is my first activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button button1;
Button button2;
ImageButton speaker, mute;
private Context mContext = this;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    speaker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
    mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.bg_music);
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    addListenerOnButton();
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kategori);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tahap.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
            }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, KategoriSenang.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    speaker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          mp.pause();
          speaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          mute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
          Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
          editor.putBoolean("isMuted", true); 
          editor.commit(); 

        }
    });

    mute.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          mp.start();
          mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          speaker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
          Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
          editor.putBoolean("isMuted", false); 
          editor.commit(); 

        }
    });
}
```

Then the second activity to retrieve the value from sharedpreferences

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tahap);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Tahap.this,R.raw.bg_music);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    boolean isMuted = prefs.getBoolean("isMuted", false);
    if (isMuted=true){
        //mp.stop();
        mute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        speaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speaker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mp.start();
    }
```

the application has stopped unexpectedly.

here is the logcat

> 04-12 01:55:13.803: D/JpgDecHal(6002): JpgDecHal::JpgDecHal
>   04-12 01:55:13.803: W/JpegDecDriver(6002): Open JPEG Driver Error (Permission denied)
>   04-12 01:55:13.803: W/JpgDecHal(6002): [JPEG Decoder] - Jpeg decoder resource is busy
>   04-12 01:55:13.803: D/JpgDecHal(6002): JpgDecHal::~JpgDecHal
>   04-12 01:55:13.803: W/mHalJpgDec(6002): can't lock resource
>   04-12 01:55:13.803: W/skia(6002): Use JPEG SW Decoder
>   04-12 01:55:13.804: D/JpgDecHal(6002): JpgDecHal::JpgDecHal
>   04-12 01:55:13.804: W/JpegDecDriver(6002): Open JPEG Driver Error (Permission denied)
>   04-12 01:55:13.804: W/JpgDecHal(6002): [JPEG Decoder] - Jpeg decoder resource is busy
>   04-12 01:55:13.804: D/JpgDecHal(6002): JpgDecHal::~JpgDecHal
>   04-12 01:55:13.804: W/mHalJpgDec(6002): can't lock resource
>   04-12 01:55:13.805: W/skia(6002): HW Not support format
>   04-12 01:55:13.805: W/skia(6002): Use JPEG SW Decoder
>   04-12 01:55:13.811: D/skia(6002): jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1028!!!
>   04-12 01:55:13.819: D/MediaPlayer(6002): mPlayerID = 326
>   04-12 01:55:13.836: D/AndroidRuntime(6002): Shutting down VM
>   04-12 01:55:13.836: W/dalvikvm(6002): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b6a8)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.downsyndromemobilelearningsystem/com.example.downsyndromemobilelearningsystem.Tahap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1755)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1774)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:157)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1001)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3841)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at com.example.downsyndromemobilelearningsystem.Tahap.onCreate(Tahap.java:36)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1719)
>   04-12 01:55:13.839: E/AndroidRuntime(6002):     ... 11 more

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: Where u init the mute and speaker. use condn like this . 
if(isMuted){
}else{
}

Comment: after i had init the mute and speaker, there is no error. but the problem is, when i had click for mute, when intent to next activity the sound still playing.