# Using AudioManager interferes with call audio

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, speakerphone

I'm using the following code in a BroadcastReceiver (phone state listener) to enable speakerphone:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    }
}, 500);
```

This happens when a new outgoing call is initiated via my app. When the call is disconnected, I turn speakerphone off:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

This all seems to work well...the first time. Afterward, my phone's audio streams seem to be tangled up into a mess. Subsequent calls are strangely silent, even calls made from outside my app's code (where the settings above are not triggered). I can get call audio back seemingly at random, but I'm not sure what causes it to return.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? Is there an Android bug I'm not aware of? How can I avoid silencing my audio for subsequent calls?

**EDIT:** I'm testing on a Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue. It seems the code that was screwing up my audio was this line:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

I had used this method because I couldn't get the speakerphone setting to engage successfully without it (I found a suggestion to set the mode in another Stack Overflow answer...it worked, but had problematic consequences).

All I really had to do was remove this line and increase the handler delay from `500` to `2000`.

I've also maintained a static reference to the AudioManager as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14100651/2209048). It doesn't seem to be necessary in this particular case, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First of, I will copy this text from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode(int)) of setMode, just to be sure you are having it into account:

```
The audio mode encompasses audio routing AND the behavior of the telephony layer.
Therefore this method should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide 
management of audio settings or the main telephony application
```

In other words, only une application on the system should be toying with this kind of methods. If done otherwise, consistency is not assured.

Then I would check your different audio streams in case you have some of them too low ( STREAM_VOICE_CALL, STREAM_SYSTEM, STREAM_RING, STREAM_MUSIC or STREAM_ALARM). And maybe try to use `setStreamMute` instead of setSpeakerphoneOn.

It would be helpful to know if your application is in fact replacing `the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I ended up solving my own problem, your answer spurred me in the right direction. Good job.